# ¿Como rotar un objeto a hacia los lados sin que se volteen o giren 360 grados?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Mi problema es que necesito que un objeto, en si es el brazo de mi personaje el problema es que este como mi código creo que es muy amplio y quiero colocarle restricciones como que no tenga un capacidad de giro de 360 grados o que solo se mantenga en el frente porque es un brazo arma, es decir que este se va mantener hacia el frente como una pistola,pero se puede rotar hacia los lados, arriba y abajo solo para apuntar el objetivo.

Mi código:

```
objetodejuego[0].transform.Rotate((Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * velocidad * Time.deltaTime), (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * velocidad * Time.deltaTime), 0, Space.World);
```

Comment: El juego es 2d o 3d?

Comment: Es un juego 3d. Gracias.

Comment: es vista en primera persona no?

Comment: Si es vista en primera persona.Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré mi solución y la adapte a mis parámetros :

```
     public float sensitivity = 10f;
 public float maxYAngle = 80f;
 private Vector2 currentRotation;

 void Update () {

     currentRotation.x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity;
     currentRotation.y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;
     currentRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.x, -maxYAngle, maxYAngle);
     currentRotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.y, -maxYAngle, maxYAngle);
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation.y,currentRotation.x,0);
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
         Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

 }
```

Encontré la respuesta aquí: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1344322/free-mouse-rotating-camera.html